# Angular Dart firebase Email and Password Authentication

Tags: firebase, dart, angular-dart

I'm using firebase auth service in my mobile App. Now I'm trying to create a web page using angular-dart. Unfortunately I could not find any guide for email-password firebase authentication sample for angular-dart, like angularfire2 (https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/tree/master/docs). Please help me.

Comment: Why are you not using Firebase authentication? (I haven't tried Firebase with Dart myself yet, but I assume it is supported)

Answer (score 1):

There is [`package:angular_fire`](https://github.com/matanlurey/angular_fire), which is being built by Matan (an AngularDart team member). I'm not sure if it has email+password auth yet, though.

If not, you'd have to roll your own component for this. Outside AngularDart, [this](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-dart/tree/master/example/auth) is how you'd do that. It should be relatively straightforward to make this into an AngularDart component.

Answer (score 0):

Some time has passed, there are now good examples. [FirebaseExtended GitHub Repo](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firebase-dart) has examples for everything Firebase.

The auth example from the repo [is here](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firebase-dart/tree/master/example/auth)